# Sed: apply substitution to captured group

Tags: awk, sed

I'm running the following command

```
find ./ -type f -exec sed -i -r "s/name='(REGEX)' value='REGEX'/name='\1' value='\1'/g" {} \;
```

The captured group \1 outputs something like:

```
MainCategory[ChildCategory][GrandchildCategory][GeatGrandchildCategory]
```

What I'm trying to do is replace (using the same sed command) all square brackets with periods in value only, the expected output would be:

```
name='MainCategory[ChildCategory][GrandchildCategory][GeatGrandchildCategory]' value='MainCategory.ChildCategory.GrandchildCategory.GeatGrandchildCategory'
```

Note: MainCategory depth is unknown.

I'm trying to avoid running another sed command. Any help/suggestions is appreciated.

Comment: post the actual command. What do you mean by complex-regex?

Comment: so COMPLEX-REGEX is a variable  that has the string "MainCategory[ChildCategory][GrandchildCategory][GeatGrandchildCategory]"? and this is the only variable that you want to get rid of the square brackets?

Comment: Are there other square brackets on the line?  If not, there's no particular problem.  If square brackets can appear elsewhere on the line, then there is more challenge. As ever, showing some sample data and your best effort so far would go a long way towards improving the question.

Comment: @Jonathan Yes there are other brackets in the line that's the reason why I'm avoiding another sed command because I would have to write anothe big regex, some don't seem to understand the question.

Comment: It would really help to show an example input line and the expected/desired output — or a simplified example.  Are you trying to copy the name into the value, and then replace the square brackets in the value alone (leaving the square brackets in the name untouched)?

Comment: That's exactly what I want to do, I'm away from home so not able to post any code sample. It seems the answer to my original post is that I can't do it without using multiple sed commands.

Comment: You make life hard for people answering by not showing the situation reduced to essentials — please study how to create an MCVE ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).  Don't give up on `sed` too quickly; it is remarkably powerful, though sometimes it requires some hard thinking.  Remember, [`sed`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed) is a Turing-complete language; you can search on Google with 'sed turing complete' and get a number of references to such a proof.  That doesn't mean I'd want to code complex programs in `sed`, but …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working from the comments, it appears that if the input was (file `data.in`):

```
name='main[sub][subsub][least]' value='abs.nom.value'
name='MainCategory[ChildCategory][GrandchildCategory][GeatGrandchildCategory]' value='Diddly:Squat'
```

Then the desired output is (file `data.out`):

```
name='main[sub][subsub][least]' value='main.sub.subsub.least'
name='MainCategory[ChildCategory][GrandchildCategory][GeatGrandchildCategory]' value='MainCategory.ChildCategory.GrandchildCategory.GeatGrandchildCategory'
```

I would create a script in a file — I called it `sed.1` — like this:

```
/name='\([^[]*\)\[\([^[]*\)]\[\([^[]*\)]\[\([^[]*\)]' value='[^']*'/{
    s//name='\1[\2][\3][\4]' value='\1.\2.\3.\4'/
}
```

I still use the original `sed` regex language when I can, and in this example, it works fine, albeit a bit verbosely.
I could then run it with:

```
sed -f sed.1 data.in
```

The output is identical to `data.out`.  This assumes you can modify your complex regex to capture the four segments in separate captures.

If your complex regex cannot be modified to recognize the four parts separately, then you can still achieve the desired result.  For example (file `sed.2`):

```
/^name='\([^']*\)' value='[^']*'/{
    s//\1/
    h
    s/]\[/./g
    s/\[/./
    s/]//
    s/.*/value='&'/
    x
    G
    s/\(.*\)\n/name='\1' /
}
```

This too produces the desired output from the sample input.

Comment: Your answer pointed me in the right direction, the hold space buffer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`sed` accepts multiple expressions in the same call, just chain them with the `-e` option :

```
sed -i -r -e "s/name='(COMPLEX-REGEX)' value='ANOTHER-COMPLEX-REGEX'/name='\1'/g" -e "s/[][]/\./g"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use basic sed like below.

```
sed 's/^\([^ ]*\) \(.*\)$/\2/;s/^\[\|\]$//g;s/\(\[\|\]\)\+/./g'
```

Example:

```
$ echo 'foo MainCategory[ChildCategory][GrandchildCategory][GeatGrandchildCategory]' | sed 's/^\([^ ]*\) \(.*\)$/\2/;s/^\[\|\]$//g;s/\(\[\|\]\)\+/./g'
MainCategory.ChildCategory.GrandchildCategory.GeatGrandchildCategory
```

Answer (score 0):

```
find ./ -type f -exec sed -r -i.bak -e '/value='ANOTHER-COMPLEX-REGEX'/s/(\]\[|\]|\[)/./g' -e '/name='COMPLEX-REGEX'/s/(\]\[|\]|\[)/./g' {} \;
```

-i.bak make a backup of the original file with an extension .bak

`COMPLEX-REGEX` and `ANOTHER-COMPLEX-REGEX` - I am assuming these expression have the your square bracketed values.

Comment: No backup needed, the files are tracked by git. Resetting the branch to its original state solves any failed attempts.